# Weird space character in string, that's not a space?

Tags: ascii

I've been having trouble with a Capistrano script, or in fact, a bash command that was causing my script to fail. I kept on getting errors from the script saying:

> No such file or directory

So here's the script bit.

```
run "sudo ln -s #{shared_path}/readme.txt  #{shared_path}/readme-symlink.txt"
```

Upon closer inspection it turns out that there are two spaces between the readme.txt and readme-symlink.txt bits. By accident I found that one is a space, and the other is just a weird character that looks like a space, but it's not. Here's what it looks like in Sublime Text, configured to display whitespace:

[image: weird whitespace character]

Notice how, in the above image, there is only one dot after readme.txt, and then another "*space*"

So here's my question, what on earth is this charachter, I'm just so confused how someone managed to get that in there by typing on a normal keyboard?

Comment: It's definitely a space according to what you have pasted `echo -n "t  #" | hexdump`.

Comment: @alex You're right, it is a space, see my answer, it's the type of space that broke the script... ;)

Comment: Somewhere that non-breaking space was transformed into a regular space when you pasted it into the question.

Comment: Must be StackOverflow cleaning up the question text, I figured that might happen, so that's why I also pasted the graphic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So I pasted the string at http://www.asciivalue.com/index.php, the second space has an ASCII value of 160. According to http://www.ascii-code.com/ this is a space, but it's a non-breaking space, which I believe, the command line isn't too happy about.

[image]

Removing the nbsp fixes my script, and I can go on with my life again.

I'm just stumped about how the person that created the file got a nbsp in there in the first place.

Comment: And funny enough, the Capistrano script file is LITTERED with occurrences of normal spaces followed by non-breaking spaces. WTH!!!

Comment: It's trivial to put any character in a string. It doesn't need to exist on the user's keyboard to put it there (they can copy and paste it, or use the character code for it).

Comment: Most likely, the script was copied from a webpage. Its use is explained here. http://www.sightspecific.com/~mosh/www_faq/nbsp.html

Comment: @alex I agree, but who in their right mind copies and pastes a space followed by nbsp when they can just give the spacebar a good smack. ;)

Comment: @kaya Or maybe the person who originally created the script had a broken spacebar, and they used Command+V instead with the space character on the clipboard...(rofl)

Comment: And I get the use of nbsp, I use it all the time when doing HTML, there are other space characters too like &thinsp; etc, however, I think that's a Unicode char.

Comment: Hey thanks to the information found in this question/answer and other on the same subject we've wrote a funny post about it! I dare you to read it! :-D http://heavydots.com/blog/when-the-white-space-became-a-beast